# Automate max and mix values of a raster in my color palette on Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, legend, color-ramp

Is there a way to automate my code so that Google Earth Engine can pull minimum and maximum values from a raster and update my color palette accordingly? I'm using the following code currently.

```
// Pull the package from the GitHub repo which stores colour palettes to be used in GEE
// See https://github.com/gee-community/ee-palettes for more info
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');

// Choose the yellow, orange, red colour palette with 9 classes
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.YlOrRd[9];

// Create a mask to remove 0 values
merchantable = merchantable.updateMask(merchantable.neq(0));

// Add a raster layer and enable the colour palette
Map.addLayer(merchantable, {min: 0, max: 335, palette: palette});
```

As you can see, the minimum value of my raster is 0, and the maximum is 335.

Comment: Yes, change the min and max value to your desired variable name, you might have to add .getInfo() though it is hard to tell without a functional example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the min/max values it's easy enough of course. But if you don't, and want to have the whole thing automated, you'll first need to calculate the min/max values of the image you're trying to display, and then pass those values to the `visParams` argument of `Map.addLayer()`.

Here's a solution combining `.reduceRegion()` and `.evaluate()`. As your question doesn't have a reproducible example, I've used a DEM image of Switzerland as an example. Just replace those with whatever you're trying to display.

```
// Define region of interest
var regionOfInterest = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Switzerland'))

// Image of interest
var img = ee.Image("WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM").clip(regionOfInterest)

// Calculate min/max values
var minMax = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(), 
                               geometry: regionOfInterest, 
                               scale: img.projection().nominalScale(),
                               bestEffort: true,
                               maxPixels: 1e9})
                               
// Rename keys
var minMax = minMax.rename(minMax.keys(), ['max','min']);  

// Retrieve dictionary values and pass to visParam settings
minMax.evaluate(function(val){
  var min = val.min;
  var max = val.max;
var visParam = {
        min: min,
        max: max,
        palette: ['green', 'yellow', 'brown']
        };
        
Map.addLayer(img, visParam, "Image");
})
```

This returns:
[image]

Comment: When you bring in your image of interest, do I still need an equivalent to ("WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM") with my (user/asset-name) if I have a raster imported into my workspace (appears at the top of the script area)? I've gotten an error saying the min is undefined `Line 20: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined`. Link to show what the current working code looks like https://code.earthengine.google.com/17f45cdce28b5fbf9e2975b9b58b48db

Original code, without solution https://code.earthengine.google.com/967aa5da56bb42c29af5a8e9f0123645 @hooge048

Comment: You'll need to correct the `geometry` argument of the reducer: this needs a `Geometry` object (now you're using an `Image`). Change it to `geometry: merchantable.geometry()`, then it works.